# select multiple controls at runtime just what we can do at design time

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am developing an application, I need some idea to select multiple control in the run time environment  A just what we can do at design time

as of now i can select one control at a time but i need to select multiple controls at runtime 
for example we do Ctrl+click to select multiple controls at design time
i am trying to achieve same thing same thing at runtime

please help!!!!!!

Comment: Asking the same question [VS IDE like application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12870195/745969) in 30 minutes will not get you an answer...it will, however, most likely get your question closed.  Your question is a little broad - what have you tried? What code do you have so far?

Comment: i can select one control at a time (at runtime) but now i want to select multiple control to allign the controls accordingly just what we do in (at design time)VB2005

Comment: @Tim i am using this code foe time being but it doesnot allow me to select multiple control http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5090/Simple-Runtime-Control-Sizing-and-Dragging-Class

Comment: When people dont Know the answers they closed the questions